# Why do Python's win32api.keybd_event conflict with win32clipboard.OpenClipboard()?

Tags: python, winapi, clipboard

please see the picture:
[image: problem]

the code is:

```
import win32con
import win32clipboard
import win32api

win32api.keybd_event(win32con.VK_SNAPSHOT, 0, 0, 0)
win32api.keybd_event(win32con.VK_SNAPSHOT, 0, win32con.KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0)

win32clipboard.OpenClipboard()
win32clipboard.CloseClipboard()
```

What more strange is that while I write the code in Python's interactive environment, everything is OK like the picture:
[image]

In conclution: if I save the codes in a `.py` file and `python xxx.py`, then the error raised, but if I write the code in the interactive environment, everything is OK.

Please tell me why and how to solve the problem if I need to write the code in a `.py` file. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem Solved.
The Solution is So Simple. Just one more line code.

```
import win32con
import win32clipboard
import win32api
import time

win32api.keybd_event(win32con.VK_SNAPSHOT, 0, 0, 0)
win32api.keybd_event(win32con.VK_SNAPSHOT, 0, win32con.KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0)

#this is the solution
time.sleep(1)

win32clipboard.OpenClipboard()
win32clipboard.CloseClipboard()
```

And this is because while `win32api.keybd_event` send the print screen key, it will not wait until the screenshots finished. Instead, it will continue to run the follow code. But in this time, the screen is being printing, the clipboard is using, so win32clipboard can not get the clipboard.